# How to add a button beside search box in bootstrap 3 table

Tags: javascript, html, button, bootstrap-4

I need to add a button beside the search box, because the search box is from bootstrap i cant insert a button beside it

i already tried this https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/pageLength-select.html but the button not showing up (i already add js and css library for bootstrap)

Here is my code

```
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>No</th>
                <th>Request Type</th>
                <th>Request ID</th>
                <th>Requester</th>
                <th>Traveler Employee</th>
                <th>Pending Approver</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Status Reason</th>
                <th>Stage</th>
                <th>Request Date</th>
                <th>Due Date</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>              
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Travel Request</td>
                <td>TR000001</td>
                <td>Matthew Man Young Leemans</td>
                <td>Matthew Man Young Leemans</td>
                <td>Matthew Man Young Leemans</td>
                <td>Initiate Request</td>
                <td>New</td>
                <td>Draft</td>
                <td>20-03-2023</td>
                <td>20-03-2023</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

```
    </script>
        <script>
          $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#example').DataTable();
    });
        </script>
```

Any help? Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this script to add a button beside the search field. For that you need data tables CDN from here https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/styling/bootstrap.html
And for position, you can add a style for this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    lengthChange: false,
    buttons: [{
      text: 'My button',
      action: function(e, dt, node, config) {
            console.log("config", config)
        alert('Button activated');
      }
    }]
  });

  table.buttons().container()
    .appendTo('#example_filter');
});
```

I hope this will help you.
Thanks

Comment: i don't know why but the button is not showing somehow, i already add the bootstrap library. Thank You